# IPython-like code completion in a script editor

Tags: python, pandas, autocomplete, ipython, editor

I have to write python scripts dealing with csv files containing many columns. Pandas data frames and IPython console are very usefull in this context because the column names are auto-completed.

But while writing my scripts, I cannot enjoy this feature in Spyder's text editor because its code completion is only based on static code analysis. I have the same problem with Jupyter Lab. I have made some search but so far I have not found the proper tool.

So here is my question : is there a Python script editor providing "dynamic" code completion like IPython ?

[This closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571438/ipython-like-code-completion-in-text-editor) is very similar. Is there a more up-to-date solution ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: To provide this dynamic completion it has to actually run the code, loading the csv etc.

Comment: @hpaulj Of course. With Spyder, when I load the csv in the console, the editor does not know it because the two are separate. Then editor's code completion cannot help me. With Matlab for example, the editor and the variable workspace are linked. I would need a similar feature with python.